# How to replace specific string with regular expression in sublime text?

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I have a project where there is a function named `get_descriptioin('string_value')` almost every file.
So I want to keep only `string_value` and **remove** `get_description()` from all files at once. I tried several ways but I can only select and remove phrases like `get_descriptioin` (or `get_descriptioin('string_value'`), not just the specific ones that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \bget_description\((.*?)\)
Replace: $1
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you very much @Tim
It worked fine. :)